# Autocomplete adds [nid:<nid>] to node references

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax

I am using the References module for my content types. There are two content types: A and B. Nodes of one type have a reference to nodes of the other type.

I have a node titled *ABC* and I want to refer it in another node; the autocomplete in the reference field returns me *ABC[nid:5]* while I want just to have *ABC*.

How can I resolve this in simple way? Do I need another module?

Note there are nodes with the same title.

The autocomplete function used by the module is the following one.

```
/**
 * Menu callback for the autocomplete results.
 */
function node_reference_autocomplete($entity_type, $bundle, $field_name, $string = '') {
  $instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);
  $field = field_info_field($field_name);

  $options = array(
    'string' => $string,
    'match' => $instance['widget']['settings']['autocomplete_match'],
    'limit' => 10,
  );
  $references = node_reference_potential_references($field, $options);

  $matches = array();
  foreach ($references as $id => $row) {
    // Markup is fine in autocompletion results (might happen when rendered
    // through Views) but we want to remove hyperlinks.
    $suggestion = preg_replace('/<a href="([^<]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/', '$2', $row['rendered']);
    // Add a class wrapper for a few required CSS overrides.
    $matches[$row['title'] . " [nid:$id]"] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">' . $suggestion . '</div>';
  }

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

Comment: This completely depends on what is returned from the function returned defined in `#autocomplete_path`. Can you edit the question and add that function?

Comment: Adding the node ID is done to help users who have to edit the reference field. Suppose there are three nodes using _ABC_ as title whose node ID are 5, 20, and 45. Users would see _ABC_ repeated three times, but they could not understand which of the nodes is being referred, and if they just need to change the reference to the node #5 into references to node #87, they would have a hell out it to understand which of those three titles is referring to node #5.

Comment: Also, I didn't check all the code used by the module, but I suspect that removing the node ID is going to break the code: at the end, the module needs the node ID, not the node title.